# Define Salary Rules that Depend on Previous Rules in Odoo

Tags: python, openerp-8, odoo-8

The Personal Income Tax of an employee is computed in bands having different percentage of the annual gross pay. The rate of tax for the first band (first 300,000.00) is 7%, 11% for the next band (next 300,000.00) and so on. Given an annual gross of 500,000.00 the total tax is (7% of 300,000.00 + 11% of 200,000.00). I have a rule with code TAXABLE_INCOME and wish to compute the Personal Income Tax. I need to define additional rules that depend on this rule.

The first rule condition type is range and depends on "rules.TAXABLE_INCOME" and has range 0.00 - 300,000.00 and the amount type is percentage and is based on "300000.00 if rules.TAXABLE_INCOME > 300000.00 else rules.TAXABLE_INCOME" and the percent is 7%.

Now the challenge is that when I try to compute a payslip I get an error that the range condition is wrong. What is the right way to define what the range condition/percentage value depend on? Do I need to assign to result as in the python code approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The salary bands can be summarized as a list `[(LowerBound, UpperBound, PercentTax),]`

The rule for a given band depends on: `result = TAXABLE_INCOME > LowerBound` while the value can be computed using: `result = ((UpperBound - LowerBound) if TAXABLE_INCOME > UpperBound else (TAXABLE_INCOME - LowerBound)) * PercentTax / 100`

The most important discovery was that whereas the sample code refers to `rules.NET` prepending `rules.` to the rule id is an error. Hence, instead of `rules.TAXABLE_INCOME` use `TAXABLE_INCOME` directly.

Comment: The most important part of this answer (for me at least) is the way you can use another rule in calculations, just write the rule code (i.e. *TAXABLE_INCOME*) without the *rules* variable (i.e *rules.TAXABLE_INCOME*)

Comment: this thing makes me awake all night